# Nutch pointed to Cassandra, yet, asks for Hadoop

Tags: nutch

Windows 10
Nutch 2.3.1
Cassandra 3.11.1

I have extracted and built Nutch under the Cygwin's home directory.

I believe that the Cassandra server is working:

```
INFO  [main] 2018-02-23 16:20:41,077 StorageService.java:1442 - JOINING: Finish joining ring
INFO  [main] 2018-02-23 16:20:41,820 SecondaryIndexManager.java:509 - Executing pre-join tasks for: CFS(Keyspace='test', ColumnFamily='test')
INFO  [main] 2018-02-23 16:20:42,161 StorageService.java:2268 - Node localhost/127.0.0.1 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  [main] 2018-02-23 16:20:43,049 NativeTransportService.java:75 - Netty using Java NIO event loop
INFO  [main] 2018-02-23 16:20:43,358 Server.java:155 - Using Netty Version: [netty-buffer=netty-buffer-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec=netty-codec-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-haproxy=netty-codec-haproxy-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-http=netty-codec-http-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-codec-socks=netty-codec-socks-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-common=netty-common-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-handler=netty-handler-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-tcnative=netty-tcnative-1.1.33.Fork26.142ecbb, netty-transport=netty-transport-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-native-epoll=netty-transport-native-epoll-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-rxtx=netty-transport-rxtx-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-sctp=netty-transport-sctp-4.0.44.Final.452812a, netty-transport-udt=netty-transport-udt-4.0.44.Final.452812a]
INFO  [main] 2018-02-23 16:20:43,359 Server.java:156 - Starting listening for CQL clients on localhost/127.0.0.1:9042 (unencrypted)...
INFO  [main] 2018-02-23 16:20:43,941 CassandraDaemon.java:527 - Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it
```

I did the following check:

```
apache-cassandra-3.11.1\bin>nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  273.97 KiB  256          100.0%            dab932f2-d138-4a1a-acd4-f63cbb16d224  rack1
```

csql connects

```
apache-cassandra-3.11.1\bin>cqlsh

WARNING: console codepage must be set to cp65001 to support utf-8 encoding on Windows platforms.
If you experience encoding problems, change your console codepage with 'chcp 65001' before starting cqlsh.

Connected to Test Cluster at 127.0.0.1:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.1 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
WARNING: pyreadline dependency missing.  Install to enable tab completion.
cqlsh> describe keyspaces

system_schema  system_auth  system  system_distributed  test  system_traces
```

I followed the tutorial '[Setting up NUTCH 2.x with CASSANDRA](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Nutch2Cassandra)' and added the respective entries in the properties and the xml files.

I go to the Cygwin prompt and attempt to crawl. Instead of using Cassandra, it asks for Hadoop(HBase, probably)

```
/home/apache-nutch-2.3.1
$ ./runtime/deploy/bin/crawl urls/ crawl/ 1
No SOLRURL specified. Skipping indexing.
which: no hadoop in (<dump of the classpath entries>)
Can't find Hadoop executable. Add HADOOP_HOME/bin to the path or run in local mode.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nutch 2 still requires Hadoop to run, it just allows you to store data somewhere other than HDFS.
The only way to run Nutch without Hadoop is local mode, which is only recommended for testing. To do that, run `./runtime/local/bin/crawl`.

Comment: Ohh. I'm a bit confused. What of the following is true in the 'deploy' mode:

1. Data cannot be stored in Cassandra, HBase is the only way.

2. Data will be stored in Cassandra but you need a (maybe, just a single node)Hadoop cluster anyway which won't be storing any data but is there just to make Nutch happy.

Comment: 1 is not true.

2 is true, if we ignore the second part 
Hadoop is made of two parts: distributed storage (HDFS) and a Map/Reduce framework. Nutch is essentially a collection of Map/Reduce tasks. It relies on Hadoop to distribute these tasks to all participating servers. So if you run in local mode, you can only use one server. If you have a single-node Hadoop, Nutch will be able to fully utilize the server, but it will still be limited to crawling from one machine, which is only sufficient for small/slow crawls.